# When to use the "identity" tmp trick?

Tags: c++

I have seen this meta function used, but never really understod why and in what context  it is required. Can someone explain it with an example?

```
template <typename T>
struct identity
{
    using type = T;
};
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

#### Trick #1

Prevents template argument deduction:

```
template <typename T>
void non_deducible(typename identity<T>::type t) {}

non_deducible(1);      // error
non_deducible<int>(1); // ok

template <typename T>
void first_deducible(T a, typename identity<T>::type b) {}

first_deducible(5, 'A'); // ok
```

---

#### Trick #2

Disables unsafe/unwanted implicit deduction guides ([c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)):

```
template <typename T>
struct smart_ptr {
    smart_ptr(typename identity<T>::type* ptr) {}
};

smart_ptr{new int[10]};  // error
smart_ptr<int>{new int}; // ok
```

---

#### Trick #3

Makes defining type-traits (and other metafunctions) easier:

```
template <typename T>
struct remove_pointer : identity<T> {};

template <typename T>
struct remove_pointer<T*> : identity<T> {};
```

---

#### Trick #4

Can be used for tag dispatching:

```
void foo(identity<std::vector<int>>) {}
void foo(identity<std::list<int>>) {}

template <typename T>
void bar(T t) {
    foo(identity<T>{});
}
```

---

#### Trick #5

Can be used for *returning* types:

```
template <int I>
constexpr auto foo() {
    if constexpr (I == 0)
        return identity<int>{};
    else
        return identity<float>{};
}

decltype(foo<1>())::type i = 3.14f;
```

---

#### Trick #6

Helps to specialize functions accepting a forwarding-reference:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
void foo(T&& t, identity<std::vector<U>>) {}

template <typename T>
void foo(T&& t) { foo(std::forward<T>(t), identity<std::decay_t<T>>{}); }

foo(std::vector<int>{});
```

---

#### Trick #7

Provides alternative syntax for declaring types, e.g. pointers/references:

```
int foo(char);
identity<int(char)>::type* fooPtr = &foo; // int(*fooPtr)(char)

identity<const char[4]>::type& strRef = "foo"; // const char(&strRef)[4]
```

---

#### Trick #8

Can be used as a wrapper for code expecting nested `T::type` to exist or deferring its evaluation:

```
struct A {};
struct B { using type = int; };

std::conditional<has_type<A>, A, identity<float>>::type::type; // float
std::conditional<has_type<B>, B, identity<float>>::type::type; // B
```

---

#### Trick #9

In the past, it used to serve as a workaround for a missing scope operator from the `decltype()` specifier:

```
std::vector<int> v;
identity<decltype(v)>::type::value_type i;
// nowadays one can say just decltype(v)::value_type
```

---

The `identity` utility is [proposed](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0887r1.pdf) to be added to [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20):

```
namespace std {
    template <typename T>
    struct type_identity { using type = T; };

    template <typename T>
    using type_identity_t = typename type_identity<T>::type;
}
```

Comment: How would you accomplish the tag dispatching with the identity meta function if the parameter was a reference (T& t)?

Comment: @KaptenMugg one would use `std::remove_cv<T>::type` for that

Comment: Ok sorry for being unclear. I meant how would you pass the reference if the tag functions also had references as parameter?

Comment: @KaptenMugg references can be removed as well `std::remove_reference<T>::type`

Comment: If we would like to pass the "t" as a reference?

Comment: @KaptenMugg I don't get your use case, you mean `identity<T&>{}`?

Comment: Yes, how would you pass parameter "t" to foo

Comment: @KaptenMugg if you were to pass `t` to `foo`, you wouldn't need a tag at all

Answer (score 18):

It introduces a non-deduced context, when deducing template arguments from function parameters. For example, say you have a function with the following signature :

```
template <class T>
void foo(T a, T b);
```

If someone were to call `foo(123L, 123)`, they'd get a substitution error, as `T` cannot match `long int` and `int` at the same time.

If you want to match only the first argument, and convert the other one implicitly if needed, you can use `identity` :

```
template <class T>
void foo(T a, typename identity<T>::type b);
```

Then `b` does not participate in type deduction, and `foo(123L, 123)` resolves to `foo<long int>(123L, 123)`.

Comment: But how does it happen that `typename identity<T>::type` becomes `int`? If only `T` from first parameter is deduced, then we have `T = long`, so second's parameter type is `typename identity<long>::type`, which in turn is `long`. Or is it that first `T` is unrelated to second `T` (which would be weird for me...)?

Comment: From future). Yes, `b` will be deducted as `long`. -> Second parameter must be implicit conversation to `long`.